# Manim command prompt error with starting tutorial

Tags: python, math, command-prompt, nameerror, manim

I'm doing the starter tutorial for Manim, and here's my code:

```
from manim import * 

class PointMovingOnShapes(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        square = Square(color=BLUE) # Create a square
        square.rotate(-3 * TAU / 8) # Rotate the square -3/8 * 2*PI
        self.play(GrowFromCenter(square))
```

Now in command prompt I wrote **manim -p -ql start.py PointMovingOnShapes**, and my command prompt gives me this error:

```
class Pith(Scene):
NameError: name 'Scene' is not defined
```

sidenote: I'm using "https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-create-mathematical-animations-like-3blue1brown-using-python-f571fb9da3d1" for my tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

If the error you posted is actually what is returned in your terminal, the most likely reason is that you forgot to save your file as `class Pith(Scene)` does not occur in the snippet you posted above.

And on a side note, I don't think it is a good idea to fix the installed version to `0.9.0`, as it (and therefore also this tutorial you are trying to follow) is rather old. You can probably follow most, if not all, of the tutorial with a more recent version as well.